# When using odesolver, how do I plot the values of an "intermediate" variable?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, solver, ode, differential-equations

I'm calling the solver with this:

```
[W,fs] = solverfun(@odefun,tinterval,f0);
```

Here is the `odefun`:

```
function derivs = odefun(W,fs,param);
    F_H2 = fs(1); 
    F_CO = fs(2); 
    F_CO2 = fs(3); 


  ...


    thiele = D_r * sqrt(k_s * rho_c / De); 
    eff = 3 / (thiele ^ 2) * (thiele * coth(thiele) - 1); 

  ....


derivs = [dF_H2dW; dF_COdW; dF_CO2dW; dF_H2SdW; dF_SO2dW; dF_N2dW; dF_H2OdW; dF_S6dW; dTdW];
```

How do I plot the values of `thiele` and `eff` vs `W`?

Answer (score 0):

The parts of code you have removed makes it unclear the dependence of `thiele` on the problem variables. However, if `thiele` was only dependent on parameters, then of course it would be constant.

It appears that `thiele` here represents the Thiele modulus. What you've shown above looks to be constant (for a first order reaction and thus independent of concentration), but perhaps you have some other dependence in the code you've omitted.

In that case, I will illustrate this for the scenario where `thiele` depends on the integrated quantity `F_x`, but is easily extendible for other dependence (on your variable `W` or a derivative). The same would apply for `eff`

**Here is a possible way of plot**

Suppose I have a variable the variable `thiele = f(F_x)` where the relationship is known (as you've shown above). Then, after `solverfun` has returned, you can do the following:

```
[W,fs] = solverfun(@odefun,tinterval,f0);
thiele = @(F_x) D_r * sqrt(k_s * rho_c * F_x / De);
plot(W,thiele(fs(:,1));
```

Note that I provided a made up function for `thiele` and picked a random column from `fs` that represents the quantity of interest. Of course if there are multiple arguments, you can extend this in the same manner.

Hope this helps.